# hide div if other div is empty in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I "just" want to hide the title of this div (#event-cdc) if the div is empty
I have this html element to test

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-fce254c elementor-invisible elementor-widget elementor-widget-jet-headline" data-id="fce254c" data-element_type="widget" id="event-cdc" data-settings="{&quot;_animation&quot;:&quot;fadeInUp&quot;}" data-widget_type="jet-headline.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h2 class="jet-headline jet-headline--direction-vertical"><span class="jet-headline__part jet-headline__first"><span class="jet-headline__label">Les évènements</span></span><span class="jet-headline__part jet-headline__second"><span class="jet-headline__label">où nous serons présent</span></span></h2>      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8ae0c27 elementor-invisible elementor-widget elementor-widget-bdt-event-list" data-id="8ae0c27" data-element_type="widget" id="event1" data-settings="{&quot;_animation&quot;:&quot;fadeInRight&quot;}" data-widget_type="bdt-event-list.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div id="bdt-event-8ae0c27" class="bdt-event-list bdt-event-calendar">
            <div class="bdt-list bdt-list-large">

                        
            </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
```

And I can just call this div #event1 with this jquery code :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $("#event1").children().length === 0 ) {
        $("#event-cdc").hide();
    }
});
```

I have also trying with this condition :

```
if ( $.trim( $('#event1').text() ).length === 0 ) {
```

Without success...

Have you an idea to help me ?

Regards

Comment: In the html you provided, there is no element with that id.

Comment: Does ur page has more html elements with id `#event-cdc`? If so then use different ids. If it is not then provide more code.

Comment: I have edit my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code provided doesn't actually show `div#event-cdc` in the markup, so we can't know for sure that the hiding piece will work, but critically neither of your conditions is evaluating as `true`.  Here's an example of the `children` of `#event1`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($("#event1").children().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8ae0c27 elementor-widget elementor-widget-bdt-event-list animated fadeInRight" data-id="8ae0c27" data-element_type="widget" id="event1" data-settings="{&quot;_animation&quot;:&quot;fadeInRight&quot;}" data-widget_type="bdt-event-list.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <div id="bdt-event-8ae0c27" class="bdt-event-list bdt-event-calendar">
            <div class="bdt-list bdt-list-large">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's an example of the `text()`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($.trim( $('#event1').text() ));
    console.log($.trim( $('#event1').text().length ));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8ae0c27 elementor-widget elementor-widget-bdt-event-list animated fadeInRight" data-id="8ae0c27" data-element_type="widget" id="event1" data-settings="{&quot;_animation&quot;:&quot;fadeInRight&quot;}" data-widget_type="bdt-event-list.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <div id="bdt-event-8ae0c27" class="bdt-event-list bdt-event-calendar">
            <div class="bdt-list bdt-list-large">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem you are running into with [`$.trim`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) is that it preserves whitespace in the middle, so it is keeping your giant whitespace output.

Regardless, `$.trim` is deprecated-- if you use the native JavaScript [`.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) it works just fine:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('#event1').text().trim().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8ae0c27 elementor-widget elementor-widget-bdt-event-list animated fadeInRight" data-id="8ae0c27" data-element_type="widget" id="event1" data-settings="{&quot;_animation&quot;:&quot;fadeInRight&quot;}" data-widget_type="bdt-event-list.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <div id="bdt-event-8ae0c27" class="bdt-event-list bdt-event-calendar">
            <div class="bdt-list bdt-list-large">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the working example using the updated code from your question:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#event1').text().trim().length === 0) {
      $("#event-cdc").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-fce254c elementor-invisible elementor-widget elementor-widget-jet-headline" data-id="fce254c" data-element_type="widget" id="event-cdc" data-settings="{&quot;_animation&quot;:&quot;fadeInUp&quot;}" data-widget_type="jet-headline.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <h2 class="jet-headline jet-headline--direction-vertical"><span class="jet-headline__part jet-headline__first"><span class="jet-headline__label">Les évènements</span></span><span class="jet-headline__part jet-headline__second"><span class="jet-headline__label">où nous serons présent</span></span></h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8ae0c27 elementor-invisible elementor-widget elementor-widget-bdt-event-list" data-id="8ae0c27" data-element_type="widget" id="event1" data-settings="{&quot;_animation&quot;:&quot;fadeInRight&quot;}" data-widget_type="bdt-event-list.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <div id="bdt-event-8ae0c27" class="bdt-event-list bdt-event-calendar">
            <div class="bdt-list bdt-list-large">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($("#div-which-will-check-to-be-empty").text()==""){
        $("#div-to-hide").css("display","none");
   }else{
        $("#div-to-hide").css("display","inline");
   }
})
```

Comment: Not working too,.. :(
I thing it is because I have some class under my div.

Comment: try `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: This doesn't work because the output of .text() in their case is not an empty string, but a string full of many whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain JavaScript.

```js
if(document.getElementById("if-no-content-div-id").innerHTML = "") {
  document.getElementById("div-to-hide-id").hidden = "true";
}
```

Then use something like `setInterval` to run it continuously, if you wish.

Comment: But the `innerHTML` of  `#event1` is _not_ empty-- it contains plenty of additional markup, just no text content to be rendered on screen.

Comment: If that is the case, then you could use `textContent`, but then again, it might not accurately detect images or non-text elements. Good point @AlexanderNied.